# val = &(a->b.c) not same as x=a->b; val = &(x.c) in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code in C:

```
char *val = &((file->chunk).a);
```

but when I do

```
struct Chunk data = file->chunk;
char *val = &(data.a);
```

it doesn't yield the same result in val. Why aren't these two the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two pieces of code have `val` pointing to two different places.

In the first example, you have an instance of `struct Chunk` at `file->chuck` and take the address of one of its members.  In the second example, you copy the contents of `file->chunk` to a *separate* instance of `struct Chunk` which resides in a different memory location.

While the contents of these two structs may be the same, they are separate objects each with their own address.  So `file->chunk.a` and `data.a` will have different addresses.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, you are creating a distinct `struct Chunk` instead of referring to the one inside `file`. Substitute:

```
struct Chunk *data = &(file->chunk);
char *val = &(data->a);
```

to get the same address.